# error Passing a String variable as filename to open a file

Tags: python, json, string, object, attributes

i have this problem: i'm tryna list all filenames from a directory and then print them with numbers on the left to let users select the file to use. Numbers are there because they match with the index of the position of filenames in the list. When i select a specific string filename in the list and pass it to

`f = open (filename, "r")

data = json.loads(f.read())`

i get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 170, in 
data = json.loads(f.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'

full code:

```
jsons=glob.glob("*.json")
print(type(jsons))
print(type(jsons[0]))
n=0
if(jsons):
    for json in jsons:
        print(str(n) + ' - ' + json)
        n=n+1

        jsonselection=int(input('select your settings file: '))
        filename=(" ".join(jsons[jsonselection].split()))
        print()
        print('your selection: ' + filename)
else:
    sys.exit(colored('no json files available.','red'))

f = open (filename, "r")  

data = json.loads(f.read())
```

actually if i pass to the method a random variable defined by me like name='file' it works.. i just can't understand why. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You've shadowed the `json` module name with the variable in `for json in jsons`

Answer (score 0):

That would most likely be because of this line of code.

```
jsons=glob.glob("*.json")
```

and then you have

```
for json in jsons:
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand what i have to change. actually the for statement prints correctly the filenames..